# ::SysFreeString() not behaving correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've run into a problem with ::SysFreeString(). It seems that when I call the following block with a large BSTR (mine is ~40,000 characters),

```
            VARIANT attValue;
            attValue.vt = VT_BSTR;
            attValue.bstrVal = attributeValue.AllocSysString();
            // use the bstrVal
            ::SysFreeString(attValue.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&attValue);
```

the string is not cleared correctly and corrupts the heap. However, with smaller (~16,000 characters) BSTR's, it works correctly and no corruption occurs. Is there an upper limit that I'm missing with the allocation or freeing?

Why is ::SysFreeString() behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO NOT call `SysFreeString()` if you are going to call `VariantClear()`, and vice versa.  `VariantClear()` frees the `BSTR` for you, this is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165.aspx):

> The function clears a VARIANTARG by setting the vt field to VT_EMPTY. The current contents of the VARIANTARG are released first. **If the vtfield is VT_BSTR, the string is freed**. If the vtfield is VT_DISPATCH, the object is released. If the vt field has the VT_ARRAY bit set, the array is freed.

You are attempting to free the same memory twice using an invalid pointer the second time, since you are not resetting `attValue.bstrVal` to NULL after calling `SysFreeString()`.

Call EITHER `SysFreeString()` OR `VariantClear()`, but not BOTH.  Calling `VariantClear()` would be the preferred solution in this example since you are using a `VARIANT` to hold the `BSTR`.

Since you are clearly using a wrapper class to allocate the `BSTR`, I suggest you use a similar wrapper class to manage the `VARIANT` for you, such as `CComVariant` or `_variant_t`.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: this block of code only caused a problem (by clearing memory twice) when the BSTR was very large. For smaller BSTR's, there was no error/crash, despite the fact that both VariantClear() and SysFreeString() were called. The root/point of my question was not how to fix the problem, but why the failure has a dependancy on the size of the BSTR.

Comment: It is **undefined behavior** to free a memory block twice.  *Anything* can happen.  The size of the `BSTR` is irrelevant to the issue.